# Fixing Eclipse errors when using Android NDK and std::vector

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I'm using eclipse to develop an  android app that also uses the ndk. I vectors in my app and I've done the necessary stuff to get them by including

APP_STL := stlport_static

In my Application.mk

Everything is working fine it compiles and runs but Eclipse keeps giving me errors when I use the vectors

```
std::vector<int> blah
```

for example creates an error. If I delete the error and keep going it compiles and runs fine.

I've added 
${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include

In my project config under C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> include

It resolves `#include <vector>` fine (before I added the path above I had an error for this) but I still get errors using the vectors.

How can I get eclipse to stop giving me errors for this?

EDIT:

example error: `Symbol 'vector' could not be resolved`

EDIT 2:

I tried to add

```
using namespace std;
```

and then using vector blah and that causes a different error:

> Invalid template arguments

Comment: You mention the word "error" 7 times in your question, but completely fail to say *what the actual error is*!

Comment: You're right I've updated the question with the specific errors.

Comment: Ah, OK. I think I know what the problem is here, but I don't know what the solution is. It *sounds like* you're mixing Java and C++, but the C++ part has got itself a bit "confused". Same thing happened to me with straight C. I gave up and went back to Vim, but that isn't exactly helpful if you want to stick with Eclipse.

Comment: I followed this little guide which let me create a mixed C++ and Java project : http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/ It works pretty well other than the problem above. Every other header file and references (for example I use the android logging header) I've used have been found except for things like the above problem for things in the stlport (but it does find the header files in there)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I've added ${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include
>
> In my project config under C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> include

Yes, that's it. I've tried to add the same with the same result.
However, if you add stl_port headers

```
${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport
```

It will do the trick. Of course it is not necessary to change

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

as it works only in eclipse indexes. It will be usefull until you are going to use something that exists in gnu-libstdc++ and doesn't exist stl-port.

Comment: Hmm, I am using stlport and the path to ${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport but I still get the error: Symbol 'vector' could not be resolved

Answer (score 2):

> Blockquote

I am suing eclipse indigo rc2.

I added following line in Android.mk

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport
```

and Added following line in Application.mk

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

then automatically  my ndk stlport path added in

> Properties -> C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> include

good luck! ^^

Answer (score 1):

At first, we met the same problem with map and tried to add "Paths and Symbols" as suggested, however it still wouldn't work.

Later on, instead of

```
#include <map>
```

we used

```
#include <stl/_map.h>
```

The error went away and then we switched back to `include <map>`. Eclipse no longer complained that "Symbol could not be resolved".

It seems eclipse has a cache and somehow it can get messed up unless you specifically tell it the right place to find the symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know at what stage it worked, but:

1. Add to Application.mk `APP_STL := gnustl_static`
2. Add include to Project properties->C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols 
   `'NDK root path'/'your directory to android platform'/arch-arm/usr/include
   'NDK root path'/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include
   'NDK root path'/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include/bits`
3. Turn off all warnings errors in Project properties->C++ General->Code Analisis.
4. Project properties->C++ Build-> Builder Settings -> Uncheck use default build command. Build command set empty.
5. Next configure NDK Builder: Project properties-> Builders-> New-> Program and fill Name (your name build conf), Location (path to NDK root directory), Working directory (path to project dir). -> Refresh and check specific resources (your libs folder in project). -> Build Options check Specify working set of relevant resources and change 'jni' folder with your source.

worked in Ubuntu 15.04. Eclipse 3.8.1. Android NDK r10e.